# How to get onReset attribute in struts2 form tag

Tags: struts2

I want to use a javascript function to get called when a form is reset. For this exists the attribute "onReset" of standard HTML form, but I'm using Struts2 tags and they don't recognize onReset as a valid attribute.

"Attribute onReset invalid for tag form according to TLD"

The tag library declaration:

<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

Anybody know how can I call a javascript function on reset of a form created with struts2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

This is actually a bug in the Struts2 form tag. The `onreset` attribute is not being passed along to be rendered as part of the output. I have [informed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3542) Apache of this bug.

**Original Answer**

Tag library attributes are case-sensitive. In fact, the Struts2 form tag does have an `onreset` attribute, but it is all lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for creating the bug report!